# Wicket REST functionality works on Jetty but not Tomcat

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jetty, wicket-6

I have created a Wicket application that has recently been upgraded with the [wicket REST functionality](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/wicketstuff-restannotations-parent).  When developing it and running through Jetty, I am able to post messages to the REST service correctly.  However when it is deployed to tomcat, going to the REST URL gives a 404 error and a 'requested resource is not available' response.

Pom entries:
wicketstuff-annotation, wicketstuff-restannotations, wicketstuff-restannotations-json (all jar/compile, version identical to wicket version 6.24.0)

Code in the rest class

```
public class Webhook extends AbstractRestResource<JsonWebSerialDeserial> {
    @MethodMapping(value="/notification", httpMethod=HttpMethod.POST, consumes= RestMimeTypes.APPLICATION_JSON, produces = RestMimeTypes.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String notification( @RequestBody Notification data ) {

        // do some things

      return "received successfully";
    }

    @Override
    public String getMountPath() {
      return "/emailcampaign/webhook";
    }
}
```

The REST class is initialized in WicketApplication:

```
public void init() {

  final Webhook hook = new Webhook();
  mountResource( hook.getMountPath(), new ResourceReference( hook.getClass().getSimpleName() ) {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     public IResource getResource() {
       return hook;
     }
   });   
}
```

The tomcat localhost_access_logs have this:

> `XX.XX.XX.XX - - [01/Feb/2018:06:46:10 +0000] "POST /emailcampaign/webhook/notification HTTP/1.1" 404 1041

The system starts up correctly, so I don't appear to be missing any jar files on deployment, so I'm at a loss.  Can anyone help please?

Tomcat 7.0.67, Jetty 7.6.3, Wicket 6.24, Spring 4.1.4

Edit: This is the content of the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>system-ui</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>configuration</param-name>
        <param-value>deployment</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>wicket.system-ui</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sw.system.ui.WicketApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>wicket.system-ui</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What are the context path and filter path (WicketFilter) ?

Comment: Hi Martin - ive added the web.xml - I dont set a context path (to my knowledge)

Comment: In that case what are `/emailcampaign/webhook` ? I guess `emailcampaign` is the name of the .war file ?

Comment: ah sorry emailcampaign/webhook is the base path relative to the application where the Webhook REST class is served.  Then that class provides a path of /notification for it's notification method.  Thus the REST URL is http://<server>/emailcampaign/webhook/notifiction

Comment: Sorry that should be: URL is http://<application_base_path>/emailcampaign/webhook/notifiction

Answer (score 1):

....aaand this was down to a rookie oversight.

On my development machine, the path to the application on jetty was http://localhost:8080.  On the deployment machine, it's http://[server_name]/theapp.  So I set the Client REST URL to point to http://[server_name]/theapp/emailcampaign/webhook/notification (ie add the theapp subpath) and it worked!

Doh but hopefully it helps someone else out.